# TWIG Exception "... EntityCategoryProxy could not be converted to int in ..."

Tags: templates, exception, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I got this exception "... EntityCategoryProxy could not be converted to int in ..."  when I wanted to make such loop in my TWIG template:

```
{% for category in categories %}     
{{category.name}}
     {% for fund in funds %}
        {% if fund.category == category.id %} <<<<<<< EXCEPTION LINE
            {{fund.fundName}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**WORKING CATEGORY RETRIEVAL (after accepted ANSWER change)**

```
    $repository2 = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('ToolsTFIBundle:Category');
    $query2 = $repository2->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->orderBy('c.name','ASC')
        ->getQuery();
    $categoryList = $query2->getResult();
```

**ALSO WORKING CATEGORY RETRIEVAL (after accepted ANSWER change)**

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine();
    $categoryList = $em->getRepository( 'ToolsTFIBundle:Category' )
                                    ->findAll();
```

"fund.category" is foreign key mapped to "category.id" via Doctrine2 ORM. Is there any option to make this loop valid and working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fund.category is not comparable with category.id because fund.category is an entity.

Use fund.category.id == category.id